# What is better to use - abstract method or method with UnsupportedException?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

Suppose I have 2 base classes with method that must be overridden in child classes:

```
public abstract class Base1 {
    protected abstract void method();
}

public abstract class Base2 {
    protected void method() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to use: abstract method or method with default unsupported exception?

Comment: Horses for courses.  Sometimes one is better; sometimes the other.

Answer (score 2):

Both shouldn't be considered as alternate approaches. There is difference between `not-supported` and `not-implemented`, ideally we should maintain this in code too.

Use `abstract` method where there is no valid and default implementation possible.

Use `UnsupportedOperationException` implementation in method where operation is not permitted/supported. For example remove method should throw this exception in Unmodifiable collections (Set/List) etc, see `Collections` class. (**Note** here that default implementation possible is throwing exception to caller)

Comment: Your point is absolutely valid and I agree with it. That being said could you explain to me then why in `AbstractCollection` method `add` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of being **abstract**?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice depends on the concrete problem that should be solved.

For example, the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface wants to include methods to manipulate the set, but also wants to provide for implementations that do not allow manipulation. In the latter case, maniplation attempts throw an exception.

On the other hand, imagine an abstract base class `HTTPServlet` similar to [the one in `javax.servlet.http`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), but wich is only allowed to deal with GET requests. This class would declare the `doGet` method as abstract because there is no sensible default implementation and it therefore *must* be provided by the inheriting class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with abstract meethod. This is what this thing is for.
Use `UnsupportedOperationException` in the rare condition where you have multiple implementations for an abstract/interface and most of them implement a method and a new implementing class doesn't.

This should be rare and be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You gave ther answer in the question already: "must be overridden" - which of your provided samples **forces** you to override? `abstract`

In addition it shows the issue at compile time.

Using `UnsupportedOperationException` will not cause any issues until running the program, which is too late when talking about quality software. And, as already stated, it serves a different purpose.